# Parsing and looping through a javascript array of objects in PHP Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, javascript-objects

I'm wanting to parse this array of objects into something PHP can read so that I can save it into the database.
Here's the array of objects, this is from a console log, and is what is being sent to my axios post:

```
"user_id": 4,
Array [
  Object {
    "cartID": "33S",
    "id": 33,
    "image": "http://myurl/uploads/5db88f40c857dtest.jpg",
    "name": "testt",
    "quantity": 1,
    "size": "S",
  },
  Object {
    "cartID": "32S",
    "id": 32,
    "image": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
    "name": "pottery",
    "quantity": 1,
    "size": "S",
  },
  Object {
    "cartID": "34S",
    "id": 34,
    "image": "http://myurl/uploads/5db8918fac485test.jpg",
    "name": "Nature",
    "quantity": 1,
    "size": "S",
  },
]
```

On PHP I have:

```php
public static function AddOrder(Request $request)
{
    $add = DB::table('Orders')->insert([
        'user' => $request->user_id
    ]);

    $items = json_decode($request->cartItems, true);

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        DB::table('order_items')->insert([
            'order_id' => DB::table('orders')->latest('user_id')->first(),
            'product'  => $item->id,
            'quantity' => $item->quantity,
            'size'     => $item->size
        ]);
    }
    return $add;
}
```

Whenever I try this I always end up get an error cartItems can't be null. I've even tried just returning cartItems before anything in `AddOrder` is ever ran but it just says that it's null. I am using axios to send it like:

```js
 axios.post('http://myurl/api/orders/create', {
    cartItems: cart,
    user_id: user.id
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

I've also tried another way

```
    let newReq = {
      user_id: 1
  };

  for(let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
      Object.keys(cart[i]).forEach((key) => {
          let newkey = 'cartItems[' + i + '][' + key + ']';

          newReq[newkey] = cart[i][key];
      });
  }
```

With that being sent, on Laravel to respond to the client I use:

```
return response()->json($request->all());
```

I get

```
Object {
  "cartItems[0][cartID]": "33S",
  "cartItems[0][id]": 33,
  "cartItems[0][image]": "http://trayvonnorthern.com/Edgewood-API/public/uploads/5db88f40c857dtest.jpg",
  "cartItems[0][name]": "testt",
  "cartItems[0][quantity]": 1,
  "cartItems[0][size]": "S",
  "cartItems[1][cartID]": "32S",
  "cartItems[1][id]": 32,
  "cartItems[1][image]": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
  "cartItems[1][name]": "pottery",
  "cartItems[1][quantity]": 1,
  "cartItems[1][size]": "S",
  "cartItems[2][cartID]": "34S",
  "cartItems[2][id]": 34,
  "cartItems[2][image]": "http://trayvonnorthern.com/Edgewood-API/public/uploads/5db8918fac485test.jpg",
  "cartItems[2][name]": "Nature",
  "cartItems[2][quantity]": 1,
  "cartItems[2][size]": "S",
  "user_id": 1,
}
```

when I do

```
return response()->json($request->cartItems);
```

It returns nothing.

Comment: When you use `$request->user_id` is it null too? Please, add a `dd($request->all());` in your question.

Comment: yeah when I do a return $request, I just get an empty array

Comment: as Jean said, please do `dd($request->all());` in the very start of your `AddOrder`, and ensure that you have got any data from axios request

Comment: Well I'm using laravel as a REST API. Isn't just returning a response to my client side gonna achieve the same thing?

Comment: `dd` returns a generated HTML page with the contents of the response in a readable format. In your case, returning `response()->json($request->all())` should suffice

Comment: you haven't currently check client side. you have to check what you have got in the server side. to ensure that axios sent your data. and then decide how to process this data, if it has been successfully sent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios doesn't seem to accept the request format I used on my previous answer, so I deleted it. However, it seems to accept requests in this format (which is what you initially used. my mistake, really):

```
let request = {
    user_id: 1,
    cartItems: [
        {
            "cartID": "33S",
            "id": 33,
            "image": "http://myurl/uploads/5db88f40c857dtest.jpg",
            "name": "testt",
            "quantity": 1,
            "size": "S",
        },
        {
            "cartID": "32S",
            "id": 32,
            "image": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
            "name": "pottery",
            "quantity": 1,
            "size": "S",
        },
        {
            "cartID": "34S",
            "id": 34,
            "image": "http://myurl/uploads/5db8918fac485test.jpg",
            "name": "Nature",
            "quantity": 1,
            "size": "S",
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, you can send the `request` object with `axios.post`. To access it on your back-end, use `$items = $request->cartItems`. There is no need to parse it.

Comment: no problem. This is now allowing me to get cartItems. awesome! Now there's one more issue. 
I've tried a foreach that looks something like:
foreach($cartItems as $cartItem) { return response()->json($item->name)} but get an error.

Comment: just returning $item returns a single object but not able to access the properties. Sorry this is my first time attempting to use a client side cart and convert it into a PHP array

Comment: @MikeShiv Are you accessing the item properties using object notation or array notation?

Comment: object notation. Since I'm on a mobile app I just get a 500 error so hard to tell there but when I try on postman I just get a invalid argument for foreach

Comment: @MikeShiv Try using array notation like this: `$size = $request->cartItems[0]['size'];`. Laravel doesn't parse your objects back into objects, but into keyed arrays.

Comment: yeah I still get a 500 with that notation

Comment: `Object {
  "cartID": "33S",
  "id": 33,
  "image": "http://myurl/5db88f40c857dtest.jpg",
  "name": "testt",
  "quantity": 1,
  "size": "S",
}`

Comment: that's how it look when I do `foreach($request->cartItems as $item){ return $item}`

Comment: @MikeShiv Try `return $item['size'];` and show me the output

Answer (score 0):

When sending Objects or Arrays to Laravel API using Axios, try converting the payload to JSON string.

Try this on your client side

```
const your_payload_object = { user_id : 1, cart_items:[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}] };

axios.post(url, JSON.stringify(your_payload_object), {"Content-type": "application/json"})
```

You can access the data on laravel like

```
$userId = $reequest->user_id;

$cart_items = $request->cart_items;

// Which will be an array as given below
//
// $cart_items = 
//      [ 
//         ["id" => 1], 
//         ["id" => 2], 
//         ["id" => 3] 
//      ];
```